# How to create a tar.gz file from a folder excluding a folder

Tags: tar, compression

How do I exclude a file or folder while creating a tar.gz file with tar command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple example, creating a gzipped tarball out of a directory, excluding a subdirectory and listing the contents:

```
$ ls fruit/
apple  banana  peach  tomato
$ tar czf onlyfruit.tar.gz --exclude=tomato fruit/
$ tar tf onlyfruit.tar.gz 
fruit/
fruit/peach/
fruit/apple/
fruit/banana/
```

Comment: I hate to be a pedant, but a tomato is technically/botanically speaking a fruit as well :)

Comment: This would be a nice discussion at http://cooking.stackexchange.com/ ;D

Answer (score 9):

use the `--exclude=directory` flag. Works like a charm.